# Android - Which structured layout to use for repeating element - Game

Tags: android, button, gridview, android-gridlayout

I am building a game which has X number of levels.

- The "Levels" view will display a button for each level, with that
  button's value equaling to the "value" of the level (iteration),
  beginning at (0), and each level [value] incrementing by (1).
- The
  number of buttons [actual] will correlate to the number of levels in
  the game.
- The number of levels can be changed at any time (per the
  developer)

Please refer to the attached image. Which dynamic view/layout should I use?

- Gridview
- gridlayout
- tableview

...etc

If I change the number of levels [X], the number of buttons (and their values) should be dynamically created automatically.

[image: This is how i want to do]

Comment: @Rob Scott thank you very much. this helped me alot. but i have a little doubt. How can i change background color of already played level.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`.
It have several [advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31199952/7658268) over GridView, etc.

If you don't know how to use RecyclerView, there's plenty of great [tutorials](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) out there.
After you set up your RecyclerView, you will have:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then in your code add this one line

```
recycler_view.apply {
    //...
    layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 5)
}
```

Comment: i used the @rob scott suggested method and i got my desire look but one thing i want to know more. For example a player already crossed 10 level and currently playing 11th level than how can i change background color of played level so that it differentiate with level still not played.

Comment: @Krishgogar in the data model, you should have a boolean like `isCompleted`. Then you just need to check in the adapter, and change bg color accordingly.